Singularity of singularities and second microlocalization: a question that come from the stabilization of damped wave equation
In the paper [2], the Authors introduce a tool called second microlocalization, which is difficult for me. Although I have searched a lot of papers on the internet, nevertheless the material that I found is very difficult for me.
In this paper, they introduce a symbols which is very different from my "microlocal analysis" course. The symbol is a class of smooth functions of the variable $(X,\Xi,z,\zeta)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\times\mathbb{R}^{2}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ which have compact supports with respect to the $(X,\Xi)$ variables and are polyhomogeneous of degree $m$ with respect to the $(z,\zeta)$ variables, with limits in the radial direction
$$
\lim_{r\to+\infty}\frac{1}{r^{m}}a\left(X,\Xi,\frac{(rz,r\zeta)}{\|(z,\zeta)\|}\right)=\tilde{a}\left(X,\Xi,\frac{(z,\zeta)}{\|(z,\zeta)\|}\right).
$$
Then the authors say:

In order to perform the second microlocalization around the submanifold given by the equations $x=0,\xi=0$, we define, for $a\in S^{m}$,
$$
Op_{h}(a)=a\left(x,y,hD_{x},hD_{y},\frac{\epsilon(h)}{h^{\frac{1}{2}}}x,\epsilon(h)h^{\frac{1}{2}}D_{x}\right)
$$

I really don't understand the meaning of this symbol.

Is there an intuitive explanation for this formula? I don't know the variable $(z,\zeta)$ mean in the symbol $a$.

Futhermore, what does second microlocalization say? The first microlocalization says that for a distribution, the position and direction of the singularity happens, but what does the second microlocalizations say?

What is the higher order microlocalization?


We all know that, in basic calculus, the first derivative of a position function means that the velocity, and the second derivative of a position function means that the acceleration, the third derivative (although we don't know a concrete meaning)  nature life tell us that it is the second acceleration...
Does there exist a intuitive interpretation of the second microlocalization?
In addition, there are other concepts related to the concept of second microlocalization such as 2-microlocal wave front set, 2-microlocal defect measure... and so on, can anyone help me to get the main idea behind these definition?
Final note. In addition, the paper [2] by Nalini Anantharaman and Matthieu Léautaud also uses the same machinery.
Thanks in advance!!!
References
[1] N. Burq and P. Gerard "Stabilization of wave equations on the torus with rough dampings", 2020, Pure and Applied Analysis, MR4201999, Zbl 1462.35070
[2] N. Anantharaman and M. Léautaud, "Sharp polynomial decay rates for the damped wave equation on the torus", Analysis & PDE 7, No. 1, 159-214 (2014), MR3219503, Zbl 1295.35075.

@Daniele, Thank very much!

Your are welcome, monotone operator. I am glad to have been useful.

Have you taken a look at Bony's paper on second microlocalization and semilinear waves (which is cited in Burq and Gerard)? While I don't think it treats the most general way one can apply second microlocalization, it addresses a key issue, that the first microlocalization is, by design, capable of treating the intersection of two wave fronts in wave propagation, while second localization allows treating of higher order effects from e.g. the intersection of three wave fronts. The case of Burq and Gerard is slightly different, of course, since for them the singular interaction is not from ...

the nonlinear wave that is propagating against itself, but from the rough coefficients of the damping term with the wave.

@WillieWong, Thank you for your useful comment! yeah, I have read Bony's paper on second microlocalization. But unfortunately, I can't understand the relationship between the paper of Burq's and paper of Bony's. As you say, Bony's paper concerns the intersection of three wave fronts but Burq's paper deal with bicharacteristic line pass through undamped region(the damping region sometimes lies on the left some time lies on the right of the geodesic line). So, it seems that they are deal with different things, and I am confused with this.

@monotoneoperator: I think what you need to focus on is that Burq and Gerard's damped regions have checker board pattern, so boundaries have corners; these corners are like the three wave intersection. If you only treat damping supported on "half of the torus", for example, the analysis I believe does not require second microlocalization. // Admittedly I am not an expert.

@WillieWong, Wow, Thank you!your idea about "these corners are like the three wave intersection" really interesting! I think I can read these papers again now and try to understand these papers.
